# Get the last date of non-empty value using MDX

Tags: service, reporting-services, reporting, mdx

Do you know how to get the last non-empty value using mdx query.. then after that.. i want to count how many null values are next to it up to the last date. My main purpose for this is to count how many days a customer has no transaction..

i have to make a report in ssrs (using adventure works cube) that counts how many days a customer has no transaction..

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145988.aspx) article to obtain set of non empty dates.

To obtain count you can:

1. Use member properties (day of year or something more suitable in
   this case) and just subtract one value from another.
2. You can find
   last date with non empty value, previous one using LAG(1), include
   them to the next construction {prev.date:last.date} and use [COUNT
   for set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144823.aspx)

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?izul0a5b65q7r0i ... this is what i am trying to do.. the numbers on the red box is what i am going to count... finding the last non-empty value then count all the next null values

Comment: "...finding the last non-empty value then count all the next null values".
ALL or in scope of the current month? on your picture you counted only null values from the current month.

Comment: I think you can use both of my suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I follow [this article](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach/), It really helps me.
The most important part is to understand scope usage.
Even If you don't have an Enterprise Edition, you can use it.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?izul0a5b65q7r0i ... this is what i am trying to do.. the numbers on the red box is what i am going to count... finding the last non-empty value then count all the next null values